# is it necessary to free memory in Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, memory, memory-leaks, google-cloud-functions

I was doing some POC on firebase cloud functions and made a CF with below snippet (This is working code snippet).

```
app.post('/create-pdf', (req, res) => {
   pdfPromise.toFile( os.tmpdir() + '/template.pdf', (err, data) => {
       if(err) {
         console.log('Error Saving File', err);
         res.send(Promise.reject());
       }
       res.send(Promise.resolve());
    });
})

app.get('/get-pdf', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(`${os.tmpdir()}/template.pdf`);
})
```

And the call to above api will be like this.

```
axios.post(url+'/create-pdf', { data : poBody }).then((res) => {
}).then(() => {
    axios.get(url+'/get-pdf', { responseType: 'blob' }).then(res => {
        const pdfBlob = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        saveAs(pdfBlob, 'payout.pdf')
    })
})
```

This code is working fine..
I just want to know if server side code is running on GCP as CF, then do we need to clear the memory consumed by os.tmpdir(), or will it be cleared automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do need to delete the temporary files created in the temporary directory (which is an in-memory filesystem), because "files that you write consume memory available to your function, and sometimes persist between invocations".

There is a specific doc section and a video about that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips#always_delete_temporary_files and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mjfI0FYP7Y&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Renaud, Also got this https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-temp-files about dealing with tmp files

Comment: You'll also find some examples dealing with temporary files in the official [Cloud Functions samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples), in particular [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/deb2a8a18289b3f7caa816c8b35d863410133585/convert-images/functions/index.js) and [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/6c284a689c484ac4395fde1a8e8d6c2731705b55/quickstarts/thumbnails/functions/index.js)

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thanks for sharing.